# Is there any way to override the back stack button to go back to a screen with its index in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, onbackpressed

Is there any way to override onBackPress to go back to a screen with its index in jetpack compose? For example, go back to the second previous screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with backhandler function;

```
BackHandler(
   enabled = //condition if you want.
) {
   // Navigate where ever you want.
   //Example;
   navController.navigate(
      route = navController.backQueue[i].destination.route.toString()
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom  BackHandler in this case.

```
BackHandler(
   enabled = true,
   onBack  = {navController.navigate(route)}
)
```